# Bash script to start Solr deltaimporthandler

Tags: bash, shell, solr, lucene, cron

I am after a bash script which I can use to trigger a delta import of XML files via CRON. After a bit of digging and modification I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash to initiate Solr Delta Import Handler

# Setup Variables
urlCmd='http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import&clean=false'
statusCmd='http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport?command=status'
outputDir=. 

# Operations
wget -O $outputDir/check_status_update_index.txt ${statusCmd} 
2>/dev/null 
status=`fgrep idle $outputDir/check_status_update_index.txt` 
if [[ ${status} == *idle* ]] 
then 
wget -O $outputDir/status_update_index.txt ${urlCmd} 
2>/dev/null 
fi
```

Can I get any feedback on this? Is there a better way of doing it? Any optimisations or improvements would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly looks usable. Just to confirm, you intend to run this ever X minutes from your crontab? That seems reasonsable.

The only major quibble (IMHO) is discarding STDERR information with `2>/dev/null`. Of course it depends on what are your expectations for this system. If this is for a paying customer or employer, do you want to have to explain to the boss, "gosh, I didn't know I was getting error message 'Cant connect to host X' for the last 3 months because we redirect STDERR to /dev/null"! If this is for your own project, and your monitoring the work via other channels, then not so terrible, but why not capture STDERR to file, and if check that there are no errors. as a general idea ....

```
myStdErrLog=/tmp/myProject/myProg.stderr.$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d.%H%M)
wget -O $outputDir/check_status_update_index.txt ${statusCmd} 2> ${myStdErrLog}

if [[ ! -s ${myStdErrLog} ]] ; then
   mail -s "error on myProg" me@myself.org < ${myStdErrLog}
fi
rm ${myStdErrLog}
```

Depending on what curl includes in its STDERR output, you may need filter what is in the StdErrLog to see if there are "real" error messages that you need to have sent to you.

A medium quibble is your use backticks for command substitution, if  you're using dbl-sqr-brackets for evaluations, then why not embrace complete ksh93/bash semantics. The only reason to use backticks is if you think you need to be ultra-backwards compatible and that you'll be running this script under the bourne shell (or possibly one of the stripped down shells like dash).Backticks have been deprecated in ksh since at least 1993. Try

```
status=$(fgrep idle $outputDir/check_status_update_index.txt)
```

The `$( ... )` form of command substitution makes it very easy to nest multiple cmd-subtitutions, i.e.     `echo $(echo one $(echo two ) )`.   (Bad example, as the need to nest cmd-sub is pretty rare, I can't think of a better example right now).

Depending on your situation, but in a large production environement, where new software is installed to version numbered directories, you might want to construct your paths from variables, i.e.

```
hostName=localhost
portNum=8080
SOLRPATH=/solr
SOLRCMD='delta-import&clean=false"
urlCmd='http://${hostName}:${portNum}${SOLRPATH}/dataimport?command=${SOLRCMD}"
```

The final, minor quibble ;-). Are you sure `${status} == *idle*` does what you want?

Try using something like

```
 case "${status}" in 
    *idle* ) .... ;; 
    * ) echo "unknown status = ${status} or similar" 1>&2 ;; 
 esac
```

Yes, your `if ... fi` certainly works, but if you want to start doing more refined processing of infomation that you put in your `${status}` variable, then `case ... esac` is the way to go.

**EDIT**

I agree with @alinsoar that `2>/dev/null` on a line by itself will be a no-op. I assumed that it was a formatting issue, but looking in edit mode at your code I see that it appears to be on its own line. If you really want to discard STDERR messages, then you need `cmd ... 2>/dev/null` all on one line OR  as alinsoar advocates, the shell will accept redirections at the front of the line, but again, all on one line.

Comment: Shelter, this is a huge help, thank you. I created this code based on your feedback: https://gist.github.com/4101282 The only thing I didnt understand is how to do the backticks, can you tell me what you are referring to?

Comment: doah, forgot to include example/alternate. see edits in that section and comment re alinsoar's answer.  Good luck to all.

Comment: Thank you for the update, is this what you meant? https://gist.github.com/4101282

Comment: yes, looks good. You'll need to put your curl cmd inside the `*idle*` case selector of course. You can make your own path structure to hold the stdErrLog, and you'll need to make sure those directories are created. Good luck to all.